# Receiving error when using setState within fetch to set response data and boolean value of state

Tags: reactjs, fetch, loading, wordpress-rest-api, setstate

I am relatively new to React and am trying to call the WordPress API to display a featured post on my homepage. I want to show a loading icon before the fetch request returns the featured article. If I simply use:

```
this.setState({
   feature: feature
});
```

within the fetch response, the featured article is returned successfully and displayed. When I add:

```
this.setState({
   feature: feature,
   isloading: false
});
```

I receive an error in my console and the whole app blows up.

```
invariant.js:42 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {featureProject}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Here is the full component for context:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loader from './../Loader.js';

import './../../../styles/home.scss';

class Home extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        feature: [],
        articles: [],
        isloading: true
    }
}

componentDidMount() {

    let featureUrl = ' myURL /wp-json/wp/v2/projects?featured_case_study=1';
    fetch(featureUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        const feature = response.filter(feature => feature.acf.featured_case_study === true);
        this.setState({
            feature: feature,
            isloading: false
        });
    })

    let articlesUrl = ' myURL /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=4';
    fetch(articlesUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            articles: response
        });
    });

}

render() {

    let isloading = this.state.isloading;

    let featureProject = this.state.feature.map((feature, index) => {
        return (
            <div className="hero" key={index} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${feature.acf.featured_image.url})` }} >
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col s12 m8 l6">
                            <p className="projectType">Case Study</p>
                            <h2>{feature.title.rendered}</h2>
                            <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: feature.acf.lead_in} } />
                            <Link to={`/case-studies/${feature.slug}`} className="btn grey lighten-5">View Case Study</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })

    let articles = this.state.articles.map((article, index) => {
        return (
            <li key={index}>
                <h5>
                    <Link to={`/articles/${article.slug}`}>
                        {article.title.rendered}
                   </Link>
                </h5>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: article.excerpt.rendered} } />
            </li>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div className="home">

            {isloading ? (
                <Loader />
            ) : ( 
                {featureProject}
            )}

            <div className="container">
                <div className="about row">
                    <h3>User Experience Design, Usability Research <br/>&amp; Frontend Engineering </h3>
                    <h4>We drive business growth by creating digital products and services that are guaranteed to improve your bottom line. We combine an understanding of leading edge technology with a user-centered and collaborative design methodology to create valuable, usable and streamlined software.</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <h3>Recent Articles</h3>
                    <ul className="list">
                       {articles}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

};

export default Home;
```

With the code this way, I see the loading icon as it's initially set to true in the state, but when the fetch returns the featured article, that's when I get the errors and app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis are for JSX syntax. Remove them:

```
{isloading ? (
  <Loader />
) : 
  featureProject
}
```

Also, If you're not using multiline might as well remove them from JSX too:

```
{isloading ? <Loader /> : featureProject}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need the brackets around featureProject. It should be:

```
        {isloading ? (
            <Loader />
        ) : ( 
            featureProject
        )}
```